How to find trail ruins?
Minecraft added the new trail ruins in the new update, how do I find them quickly?

There are various screenshots on the wiki page. You can always use /locate if you are using cheats.

Try to find a few blocks of terracotta along with gravel or sand protuding above the surface in taiga, snowy taiga, old growth spruce taiga, old growth pine taiga, old growth birch forest, and jungle biomes.
These are the only biomes in which trail ruins can currently be found.

If you're OK with commands, you can use the /locate command.
Run /locate structure trail_ruins. It will return a chat message like

The nearest minecraft:trail_ruins is at [X, ~, Z] (# blocks away)

You can use this command in synergy with the /tp command, and run /tp @s X ~ Z (using the X and Z values from before) to teleport you to it.
Warning: This tp command uses ~ for your Y level which keeps it the same as before. If you are below ground when running the command, you will be teleported into the earth under the ruin.
If you don't fancy teleporting, you can use the F3 screen to see your coordinates and make your way there normally. The only downside to this method is that it can only return the closest ruin to you, and after you find it /locate will keep directing you to the same one. To circumvent this, you can try teleporting or walking far away after excavating, but it isn't a perfect answer.
